# Have anybody succeed installing Subtitle Edit in Wine?

Tags: software-installation, windows, wine, winetricks

Subtitle Edit has a Linux version, but it doesn't work properly, so I tried to install it through Wine. But there was some problems, don't remember exactly, it was something about 32 - 64 bit, I remember that I tried to figure this out but couldn't. My PC is 64 bit.
*I used to switch to Windows to use this application, but I fed up with Windows 10: new update, new problem, no internet now, both cable and mobile.*

Answer (score 2):

Subtitle Edit installs reasonably well on Focal Fossa 20.04 *without* installing Wine. The Subtitle Edit web site suggests the following dependencies be installed first before installing the application itself:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo apt-get install libhunspell-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpv-dev
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt-get install vlc 
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

These installed easily enough under Focal Fossa on my test system. The main application can then be installed either to `/usr/local` or, as I suggest below, in the user's `$HOME/bin`:

```
mkdir $HOME/bin && cd $HOME/bin
wget https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases/download/3.5.18/SE3518Linux.zip
unzip SE3518Linux.zip
```

I did not bother with setting a Desktop file with icons and the like, although this could be done easily enough I suspect. A double click on the file `$HOME/bin/SubtitleEdit.exe` opened up the application well enough as you can see from the screenshot below:

[image]

Hopefully this will work as easily on your own system...

Comment: Actually I had it installed on my system, though without installing libmpv and tesseract. The problem isn't installation, Linux version doesn't work properly, there is a problem with shortcuts, assigned shortcuts don't work. libmpv could be the fault right?